# Cassius and Hamlet

Tags: haskell, web, hamlet

I've used to hamlet to produce an internal stylesheet as follows:

`style = [hamlet|<style type=text/css> h3 {margin-bottom: 0}  |]`

How might this be rewritten to use Cassius/Lucius instead of plain text?

Answer (score 1):

```
toWidget [lucius|
h3 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
|]
```

Will produce a Yesod widget which contains your CSS. The Yesod book http://www.yesodweb.com/book has some very enlightening examples of this kind of thing.